# Cypress - Loop looking for data and refresh if not found

Tags: cypress

I need to loop looking for an item in a table and if it's not found, click a refresh button to reload the table. I know I can't use a simple while loop due to the asynchronous nature of cypress. Is there another way to accomplish something like this.

I tried to tweak an example from another post but no luck. Here's my failed attempt.

```
    let arry = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 60; i++) { arry.push(i) }
    cy.wrap(arry).each(() => {
        cy.get('table[class*="MyTableClass"]').then(function($lookForTheItemInTheTable) {
            if($lookForTheItemInTheTable.find("MySearchValue")) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                cy.get('a[class*="selRefreshTable"]').click()
                cy.wait(2000)
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) is bundled with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs). Instead of using a for loop, you can the [`_.times()`](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/times/). However, I wouldn't recommend this for your situation as you do not know how many times you would like to reiterate.

You'll want to use the [cypress-recurse plugin](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) and use it like this example in that repo:

```
import { recurse } from 'cypress-recurse'

it('gets 7 after 50 iterations or 30 seconds', () => {
  recurse(
    () => cy.task('randomNumber'), // actions you want to iterate
    (n) => n === 7, // until this condition is satisfied
    { // options to pass along
      log: true,
      limit: 50, // max number of iterations
      timeout: 30000, // time limit in ms
      delay: 300 // delay before next iteration, ms
    },
  )
})
```

Even with the above mentioned, there may be a simplified approach to solving your problem with setting up your app to have the table always display what you are seeking on the first try.

Comment: Thank you for this info. As you suggested, I found another way around this instance of the problem but I suspect another flavor of it may arise.  I'll definitely keep this solution in mind if/when it does.